# Sorting a dict by value in GET query with eve REST API

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, eve

I have the following schema in my domain configuration :

```
DOMAIN = {
  'adv': {
    'schema': {
      '_id': {'type': 'string'},
      'matchups': {
        'type': 'dict',
        'schema': {
          'name': {'type': 'string'},
          'value': {'type': 'double'}
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

although sorting by `_id` works :

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/adv/?sort=[("_id",1)]
```

sorting by dict value or name doesn't work :

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/adv/?sort=[("matchups.value",1)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting by subdocument fields is not supported at a regular endpoint. You could however use a [MongoDB Aggregation endpoint](http://python-eve.org/features.html#mongodb-aggregation-framework) to achieve similar result.